# Are Hyperbolic Groups Residually Amenable

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

It is a well-known conjecture (or maybe just a question) that all hyperbolic groups are residually finite. What happens if we weaken the conclusion; in particular

Are all hyperbolic groups residually amenable?

What is known in this direction?

Comment: What are known examples of groups which are residually amenable but not residually finite?

Comment: Since f.g. Nilpotent groups are residually finite, at least residually nilpotent always implies residually finite.

Comment: @unknown(google): Baumslag solitar groups are residually solvable, hence residually amenable. Certain of these are not residually finite.


Comment: @unknown: In the world of discrete groups;There are amenable groups that are not residually finite, take for example the wreath product $G\wr H$ with $G$ and $H$ amenable and $G$ non-abelian, (in fact there are also infinite and simple ones).  As far as non-amenable examples, just take one of the examples above and then take a (direct or free) product with a residually finite non-amenable group (eg. $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Proposition 7 of this paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~arjantseva/Abs/asymptotic.pdf) establishes that every hyperbolic group is residually amenable iff every hyperbolic group is residually finite.

Comment: You're welcome! The conjecture below Proposition 7 looks interesting, doesn't it?

Comment: In case the link goes down, the paper is: Asymptotic approximations of finitely generated groups, Goulnara Arzhantseva.

Comment: For reference, the result in the linked paper is Proposition 2.7. The argument is actually easy. Suppose there is a non-residually finite hyperbolic group. Then, by a couple of standard theorems, there is an infinite hyperbolic group $G$ with property (T) and no proper finite quotients.  But it is residually amenable, and every amenable quotient of a (T) group is finite, contradiction.